# How To Connect NSUserDefaults To UISwitch?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, settings, nsuserdefaults

So I have setup my settings bundle which works in the iPhone's settings app.  I want to add one of the settings within my own app.  I know I can use InAppSettings framework, but I just want to add one settings, not all of them, and I already have an page ready that I want to add this settings option to.

So I have replicated the cell with `UISwitch` in my app which looks the same as the settings one.  My question is, how can I now connect this `UISwitch` to my `NSUserDefaults` so it functions as a settings `UISwitch`?

In my appDelegate, I have:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSDictionary *appDefaults = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"No" forKey:@"isKgs"];
[defaults registerDefaults:appDefaults];
[defaults synchronize];
```

Edit - All related code:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setBool:NO forKey: @"isKgs"];
    [defaults synchronize];
}
```

The cell inside the app where I want the UISwitch to be

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     UISwitch *switchView = [[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
     cell.accessoryView = switchView;
     [switchView addTarget:self action:@selector(switchChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
     [switchView setOn:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"isKgs"] animated:NO];
     [switchView release];
}
```

And the settings bundle where I have the same UISwitch that can be acceded through iPhone settings app:

[image]

Edit 2:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
if (nil == [defaults objectForKey:@"isKgs"])
{
    [defaults setBool:NO forKey: @"isKgs"];
}
else
{

}
[defaults synchronize];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easier to use a boolean variable if you want to use a UISwitch. In the app delegate, set the default value for the settings, if not existed:

```
// set the default settings 
NSString *testValue = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"testSwitch"];
if (!testValue) {
     // since no default values have been set, create them here
     [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"testSwitch"];
     [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}
```

And then create use the value from the NSUserDefaults settings to turn on the switch if needed:

```
 UISwitch* testSwitch = [[[UISwitch alloc] init] autorelease];
 if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"testSwitch"]) {
    [testSwitch setOn:YES animated:NO];
 }
```

Comment: Thanks aporat, but is it possible to just use the key I was using in the original question rather than the boolean?

Comment: yeah, but why? :-)  NSString* setting = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"isKgs"];
  
  if ([setting isEqualToString:@"No"]) {
    [testSwitch setOn:YES animated:NO];

  }

Comment: That did not work.  If I change the value in the settings app, it should be the same in the table with this UISwitch, but its not the same.

Comment: I think you accidentally set the user default settings to OFF everytime your application starts. I have edited my question. try now

Comment: Ok thanks.  When I change the switch in the view, I get this error and crash `-[MoreViewController switchChanged:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5d223f0` and `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[MoreViewController switchChanged:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5d223f0`

Comment: good. it means it's working. add a function called switchChanged:(id)sender to your controller

Comment: I tried this but its still crashing: `- (void)switchChanged
{
    if (unitSwitch.selected == YES)
    {
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"isKgs"];
    }
    else
    {
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:NO forKey:@"isKgs"];
    }`

Answer (score 1):

You should head aporat's suggestion and use a `BOOL` instead. However, if you are insistent on using a string as in your question, then you will have to do this:

```
   if ([[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"isKgs"] isEqualToString:@"No") {
      [switch setOn:NO animated:NO];
   }
```

However, if you use a `BOOL`, you can set the switch in one simple line:

```
   [switch setOn:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"isKgs"] animated:NO];
```

This means that you must go back and set up the defaults like this:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setBool:NO forKey@"isKgs"];
[defaults synchronize];
```

Comment: For some reason this did not work, I posted the code in the question which did compile, but the switch change here does not affect the switch in the settings app. Any ideas why?  Perhaps I should just switch everything over to a Boolean?

Comment: @Faisal: Yes, the use the latter code, everything must be a `BOOL`. See the most recent edit above for how to set the defaults.

Comment: Thanks, so I changed the app delgate to what you put, and I used your switch code as well, however the switch in my app and the switch in the settings bundle are not being synchronized.  They should both be displaying the same value.

Comment: This is my settings bundle in case I need to modify anything here: http://www.box.net/shared/static/fyurjq7lc7e4qlrp72r0.png.

Answer (score 0):

At some point in your code you are going to have to check the switch state and write it back to userDefaults:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:[switch on] forKey:@"isKgsk"];
[defaults synchronize];
```

you can write the changes back to userDefaults in your switchChanged: function.

Also, if you always set your key to NO in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: then it will never reflect changes made in the settings app, it will always be NO.... this is probably not what you want.

Comment: Thanks Eric, I'm going to update my original question with the related code, and can you tell me what I'm missing?

Comment: Ok, can you please help me get this straightened out, because it was all working fine before I switched over to using booleans.  I want the app to default to NO when the user first opens it, unless they change the setting to YES, then it will be Yes from now on.

Comment: I just need to make those 2 methods and the settings bundle pic I have all work together.

Comment: Well then you must check to see if a key is already set for @"isKgsk" (boolForKey:), if it is not set it will return NO, you don't have to set it on the first launch.  When the user changes the switch, write the value back to standardUserDefaults as above.

Comment: Ok thanks, I added updated code, what should I added in the else statement though if a key exists, how can I fetch it?

Comment: If the key does not exist you will get a NO back from getBoolForKey:, so that means, just set the switch to whatever you get back and when the switch is changed (switchChanged:) write the results of [switch on] back to userDefaults.  it's very simple.  I think you are over thinking this a bit. :-)

Comment: I'm definately more confused than when I started.  Everything was working fine with the diction stuff, for some reaon now with BOOL everything is messing up.  Can you please show an example?  I need a method in my app delegate, and one in my viewController with the UISwitch, then I need them all to synchronize with the settings bundle.